# Docker Ruby Bundle Permissions Error on Build

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-compose, bundler

Using docker-compose, I'm trying to build a Ruby application (`ruby-app`). However near the end of the build it errors out:

```
There was an error while trying to write to `/ruby-app/Gemfile.lock`. It is likely
that you need to grant write permissions for that path.
ERROR: Service 'ruby-app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install --jobs 4' returned a non-zero code: 23
```

Not sure why this permissions error is cropping up now, it has been building fine for some time.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that I modified the `Gemfile` and I was expecting bundler inside of the container to generate the new `Gemfile.lock` based on the changes.

To fix the issue, I ran `bundle install` *outside* of the container. This generated a new `Gemfile.lock` on my local filesystem and then I was able to build the container as expected.